# Is $|\sin x|$ differentiable at $2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: calculus

Just to check since I'm not sure about this one:

> Is $|\sin x|$ differentiable at $2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb N$?

If so then does the derivative at $2k \pi$ equal zero?

Comment: If you look at the graph of the function, what would you guess?

Comment: $|\sin x| \approx |x|$ near zero. What does that suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, it suffices to show $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.  It's easiest to do this from the definition.

If $0 < h < \pi$, then 
$$
    \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{|\sin(h)|}{h} = \frac{\sin(h)}{h} \to 1 
$$
as $h\to 0^+$.  On the other hand, if $-\pi < h < 0$, then 
$$
    \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \frac{|\sin(h)|}{h} = \frac{-\sin(h)}{h} \to -1 
$$
as $h\to 0^-$.  Since $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ does not exist, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.
Here is a picture of the graph of $|\sin x|$:
[image]

You can see that it has a **corner** at multiples of $\pi$, so it is not differentiable there. It's called a *corner* when the slope on the left side and on the right side are both clearly defined, but different.

**P.S.:** If you want, you can then prove that it's not differentiable by computing the left-hand and right-hand limit of $\frac{|\sin (2 \pi k + h)| - |\sin (2 \pi k)|}{h}$, as $h \to 0$, and showing they do not agree.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

**Hint:** Try to prove it by definition: given $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, show that:
$$\lim_{x\to 2k\pi} \dfrac{|\sin x|-|\sin 2k\pi|}{x-2k\pi}$$
doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Let's restrict us to the case $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ for simplicity. Since $\sin x$ is nonpositive when $x\in [\pi, 0]$ and nonnegative when $x \in[0,\pi]$, we have that
$$ 
|\sin x| = \begin{cases} {-\sin x} &\mbox{if } x \in [-\pi, 0] \\ 
\sin x & \mbox{if } x\in (0,\pi] \end{cases}.
$$
Let's differentiate each part by itself. For $x\in (\pi, 0)$ 
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}|\sin x| = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(-\sin x)= -\cos x $$
and for $x\in (0,\pi)$
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}|\sin x| = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\sin x) = \cos x.$$

Let's consider now $x = 0$, i.e. with $k = 0$, and we look at the two limits
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}(-\cos x) = -1\quad\quad \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}(\cos x) = 1.$$

Since the two-sided limits of the derivative of $|\sin x|$ does not exist (i.e. they are not equal), the derivative is not continuous, and hence $|\sin x|$ is said not to be differentiable at $x  =0$.

Comment: Just because the derivative is not continuous at $0$ doesn't mean $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.  But you're right that because the left and right-hand limits of $f'(x)$ exist and disagree, then $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang If a function is differentiable on an interval, then its derivative must satisfy the intermediate value property (by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_(analysis))), so in particular, the derivative can't have a step discontinuity.

Comment: @Bungo: Yes, that's what I was saying.  So it's not "the derivative is not continuous, hence $f$ is not differentiable", it should be "the derivative **has a step discontinuity**, hence $f$ is not differentiable."